# How can I manage stylesheets for different layouts dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, templates, dynamic

I am trying to build a portal where Realtors can showcase their properites. Each user can build his own set of colored **theme** but the basic layout remains same. User can only change the background colors, text colors of different block in the layout. What is the best way to manage this?

Is it good to save all the details in a database and serve up the css file? I guess this will delay the page load. Are there any other options like using XML etc?

Comment: You will want to save the variables somehow (DB, flat file, etc.) for easier editing of course, but there's no reason to generate it on every page view.  The Realtors aren't going to be fiddling with the CSS all the time, so you'll want to cache the "compiled" CSS.  Better for your server, better for the users.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by setting a class to the main `body` tag for each user, fetching from a field, may be `theme`, from the SQL Database. I had long back written a tutorial on how it works. And the same for you here:

---

## Easy way of Theming in Web

Many of us would have this question. Themes are found everywhere, but what about theming in our own websites? We have desktop themes, wordpress themes, even themes for our mobile phones. Can’t we give the same functionality in our websites? Even though we have seen many websites with theming functionalities, they seem to be hard!

### Traditional Web Theming

Now lets see how the traditional theming in web works. They have more than two stylesheets (CSS) and they use JavaScripts to replace the original stylesheet with a new one. This is very tough and tricky, as changing a stylesheet `href` is not advisable and also, old browsers do not support them!

### Proposed Easy Theming

Well, there is another better and easy way to do the same, but not replacing the DOM Elements and their attributes. As CSS is based on classes and rules, it would be better to separate the layout and presentation, and we can give the distinction by classes. Okay, enough of theories. Lets go for the practical part.

Consider a web page `XHTML 1.1`, which has a few components, namely a sidebar with links, can be given in HTML as this way:

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Themed Website</title>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="side">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <h2>A Paragraph</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.
                </p>
                <h2>A List</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now we need to add some styles to the document with the help of `<link>` tag this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

In the `style.css`, we will first add the styles to describe about the way the presentation will be.

#### Layout

First the skeleton CSS would be, for all the elements in this:

```
body {}
body .wrap {}
body .wrap .side {}
body .wrap .side ul {}
body .wrap .side ul li {}
body .wrap .side ul li a {}
body .wrap .side ul li a:hover {}
body .wrap .side ul li a.active {}
body .wrap .main {}
body .wrap .main h1 {}
body .wrap .main h2 {}
body .wrap .main p {}
body .wrap .main ul {}
body .wrap .main ul li {}
body .wrap .main ul li p {}
```

Filling up the CSS fully, gives us with:

```
body {font-family: segoe ui; background: #fff;}
body .wrap {width: 90%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden;}
body .wrap .side {width: 25%; float: left;}
body .wrap .side ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body .wrap .side ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body .wrap .side ul li a {text-decoration: none; padding: 5px; display: block;}
body .wrap .side ul li a:hover {background: #ccc; color: #0ff;}
body .wrap .side ul li a.active {background: #0fc; color: #000;}
body .wrap .main {width: 75%; float: right; background: #0fc;}
body .wrap .main h1 {margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px;}
body .wrap .main h2 {margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
body .wrap .main p {margin: 0 10px 5px; text-align: justify;}
body .wrap .main ul {margin: 0 10px 10px;}
```

#### Theming

Now our work would be identifying the themable components. Here, with the base layout, we can theme only the colours and list styles of the unordered list. Lets get those styles alone first. Being a beginner\'s tutorial, lets concentrate only on the foreground and background colours and not layouts.

```
body {color: ; background: ;}
body .wrap .side ul li a {color: ; background: ;}
body .wrap .side ul li a:hover {color: ; background: ;}
body .wrap .side ul li a.active {color: ; background: ;}
body .wrap .main {background: ;}
body .wrap .main h1 {color: ;}
body .wrap .main h2 {color: ; background: ;}
body .wrap .main p {color: ;}
body .wrap .main ul li p {color: ;}
```

Now with this set of rules, we need to add classes. Body is the top most parent of the content. So, we will be adding classes to the `<body>`and changing the rules of the others.

Lets name the first class as `.light` and the CSS for the same would be:

```
.light {color: #333; background: #f5f5f5;}
.light .wrap .side ul li a {color: #666; background: #eee;}
.light .wrap .side ul li a:hover {color: #333; background: #ddd;}
.light .wrap .side ul li a.active {color: #333; background: #0ff;}
.light .wrap .main {background: #0ff;}
.light .wrap .main h1 {color: #333;}
.light .wrap .main h2 {color: #666; background: #0fc;}
.light .wrap .main p {color: #093;}
.light .wrap .main ul li p {color: #09c;}
```

The above colours are some crazy combinations. Now lets create another theme and let everything be `grayscale`. The red, green and blue values should be the same for all the colours.

```
.grayscale {color: #333; background: #ccc;}
.grayscale .wrap .side ul li a {color: #666; background: #eee;}
.grayscale .wrap .side ul li a:hover {color: #333; background: #ddd;}
.grayscale .wrap .side ul li a.active {color: #333; background: #fff;}
.grayscale .wrap .main {background: #fff;}
.grayscale .wrap .main h1 {color: #333;}
.grayscale .wrap .main h2 {color: #fff; background: #999;}
.grayscale .wrap .main p {color: #666;}
.grayscale .wrap .main ul li p {color: #999;}
```

#### JavaScript

We are going to use **jQuery** to make our work simple. So, in the `<head>` section, we will add a link to the jQuery library, probably from the **Google APIs**.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that we are using **jQuery 1.7.2** for stability purposes. And now for the code to change, we need to add three links or buttons, which handle the theme change. So, in the HTML, lets add these three links:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap themelinks">
    <h4>Change Themes:</h4>
    <a href="" class="theme">No Theme</a>
    <a href="light" class="theme">Light</a>
    <a href="grayscale" class="theme">Grayscale</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap.themelinks {background: #fff; border-radius: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 25px;}
.themelinks h4 {margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
.themelinks .theme {margin: 0 10px 10px; padding: 3px 5px; display: inline-block; background: #eee; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; color: #f90}
.themelinks .theme:hover {background: #f90; color: #fff;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".theme").click(function(){
        var theClass = $(this).attr("href");
        $("body").removeAttr("class").addClass(theClass);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here, we are changing just the `class` attribute of the `<body>` tag, which is supported by all the browsers. We also add a `return false;` to the `.click()` function of the link, in order not to propagate to the link specified in the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag.

### The Final HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Themed Website</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {font-family: segoe ui; background: #fff;}
            body .wrap {width: 90%; margin: auto; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
            body .wrap .side {width: 25%; float: left;}
            body .wrap .side ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
            body .wrap .side ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
            body .wrap .side ul li a {text-decoration: none; padding: 5px; display: block;}
            body .wrap .side ul li a:hover {background: #ccc; color: #0ff;}
            body .wrap .side ul li a.active {background: #0fc; color: #000;}
            body .wrap .main {width: 75%; float: right; background: #0fc;}
            body .wrap .main h1 {margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px;}
            body .wrap .main h2 {margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
            body .wrap .main p {margin: 0 10px 5px; text-align: justify;}
            body .wrap .main ul {margin: 0 10px 10px;}

            .light {color: #333; background: #f5f5f5;}
            .light .wrap .side ul li a {color: #666; background: #eee;}
            .light .wrap .side ul li a:hover {color: #333; background: #ddd;}
            .light .wrap .side ul li a.active {color: #333; background: #0ff;}
            .light .wrap .main {background: #0ff;}
            .light .wrap .main h1 {color: #333;}
            .light .wrap .main h2 {color: #666; background: #0fc;}
            .light .wrap .main p {color: #093;}
            .light .wrap .main ul li p {color: #09c;}

            .grayscale {color: #333; background: #ccc;}
            .grayscale .wrap .side ul li a {color: #666; background: #eee;}
            .grayscale .wrap .side ul li a:hover {color: #333; background: #ddd;}
            .grayscale .wrap .side ul li a.active {color: #333; background: #fff;}
            .grayscale .wrap .main {background: #fff;}
            .grayscale .wrap .main h1 {color: #333;}
            .grayscale .wrap .main h2 {color: #fff; background: #999;}
            .grayscale .wrap .main p {color: #666;}
            .grayscale .wrap .main ul li p {color: #999;}

            .wrap.themelinks {background: #fff; border-radius: 10px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 25px;}
            .themelinks h4 {margin: 0; padding: 10px;}
            .themelinks .theme {margin: 0 10px 10px; padding: 3px 5px; display: inline-block; background: #eee; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; color: #f90}
            .themelinks .theme:hover {background: #f90; color: #fff;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".theme").click(function(e){
                    var theClass = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("body").removeAttr("class").addClass(theClass);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="side">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <h2>A Paragraph</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.
                </p>
                <h2>A List</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap themelinks">
            <h4>Change Themes:</h4>
            <a href="" class="theme">No Theme</a>
            <a href="light" class="theme">Light</a>
            <a href="grayscale" class="theme">Grayscale</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can check out the working demo in [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/21192).

Comment: Thanks Praveen! This should help. I am using Laravel to build my App and will work on how to fit this in. Also, the user will build the stylesheet on the fly. Will work on this and get back if required.Thanks a ton mate

Comment: This seems like a very convoluted way to theme a website.  Replace every single class on every element?  The OP's CSS is going to become monstrous if he tries to mash every single possible theme into a single file.  There's no reason to do any of that.  Alternate Style Sheets exist for a reason.

Comment: @cimmanon Nopes, he can have it in theme level stylesheets. And, just by manipulating the class, he can achieve this. We do this in our enterprise level application and it doesn't hit the performance. `:)`

Comment: @NullPointer Sent you a mail I suppose. Got it?